# how to convert predicted CSV to xml in python(jupiter notebook)

Tags: python, xml, arima

I am predicting the output data using ARIMA.
output is saved in CSV.
i need the output to be stored in XML format.

```
import numpy as np
prediction = pd.DataFrame(predictions,columns=['sl.no' 'predicted_freq']).to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the `to_csv()` method, you have a pandas dataframe. To convert one of these to xml, there are solutions (though not out of the box). See e.g. [here].(https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-xml-files-in-python-with-pandas/#writingxmlfileswithlxml)

You may have to ask yourself though, how exactly your xml needs to be structured.